# Are RTT (round trip time) statistics kept for TCP connections in Linux?

Tags: linux, tcp, roundtrip

I know definitely I can measure it by sending a package and measure the response or I can use the command ping. But is there any command or is there any folder where I can get it directly?  As the RTT is a very important factor of TCP links. I cannot find such information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the round-trip-time isn't fixed.  That is, you can't know how long a response will take before the requesting packet is actually sent.  You can have an idea, and you can accumulate statistics, but you can't ask "What's the round trip time to such-and-such server".

Comment: Yes. I know. I originally mean maybe there is a field associated with each TCP link showing the current RTT and is updated periodically. I think linux doesn't provide such information.

Comment: There's no such thing as the "current RTT".  The actual RTT depends on a wide range of factors, all of which can change on the fly.

Comment: -1. This answer is wrong. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231600/fetching-the-tcp-rtt-in-linux and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907684/extract-tcp-round-trip-time-rtt-estimations-on-linux